# Lyx citation style: et al only when four or more authors

Tags: bibtex, lyx

I am using LyX and Bibtex and I changed the bibliography style to natbib (author-year). There are multiple styles we can choose. So far, all the styles I have tried make the reference of the paper in the text appears like "Author 1 et al. (year)" as long as there are three or more authors. My goal would be to have the same but only when there are FOUR or more authors (so that for a paper with three authors the three names appear in the citation in the text).

Would you know which style would allow me to do that on LyX?
(for the context, I am trying to implement the publication guidelines from the AEA journals in economics)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you consulted https://www.aeaweb.org/journals/policies/templates and, in particular, the LaTeX templates?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I checked but I am using LyX and the aea style bibtex does not allow for three authors citations